# jQuery.clone() loses attached event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I clone a piece of the document using `.clone()` after it has had events applied to it, how do I get *all* of those events to come back with the cloned elements if I re-inject the cloned elements back into the document?

All of my attached event handlers are lost when I do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">Something <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle text-danger pull-right"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">Something else <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle text-danger pull-right"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.row').delegate('.glyphicon-remove-circle', 'click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    $reset = $('.row').clone();
</script>

<button onclick="$('.row').replaceWith($reset)">Reset</button>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eComEvo/1o8jk4pf/1/) for it.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents

Comment: As Kevin B said; read the docs. a simple extra parameter will fix your issue.

Comment: @Kevin B: Using a delegated event, but not attached to a non-changing ancestor, is the real issue. Deep cloning of event should not even be required.

Comment: I agree, that's the correct way to re-organize this code to work, however, a direct answer to the question was to simply include the parameter

Comment: @Kevin B: People usually ask for what they want. Seldom for what they actually need :)

Comment: Good thing i didn't make it an answer :) it's the wrong way to solve the problem, even if it does.

Comment: @KevinB Surprised I missed that glaring part of the docs. Been bouncing between docs and code for so long I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use a delegated event anyway, just attach it to a *non-changing ancestor* and stop worrying about element specific handlers:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1o8jk4pf/2/

```
$('.container').delegate('.row .glyphicon-remove-circle', 'click', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

$reset = $('.row').clone();
```

If you are using a recent version of jQuery, use `on` instead e.g.:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.row .glyphicon-remove-circle', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Delegated event handlers work by applying the selector after the event bubbles up to a single non-changing ancestor. Therefore there is only one point of event attachment and no worry about dynamically added elements.

Comment: Thanks! It is attached to a non-changing ancestor in my original code, BTW. I just didn't post that part for brevity sake.